# Fluent NHibernate join table mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Reverse engineering an existing database to map with N-Hibernate using Fluent N-Hibernate.

How can I map this?

## Address table

Id
Address1
Address2

## Person table

Id
First
Last

## Types

Id
TypeName

## PersonAddress table (A person can have home, business etc addresses)

Id

PersonId  (Id from person table)

AddressId (Id from address table)

TypeId    (Id from types lookup table HOME, BUSINESS etc..)

Any help would be great. Thanks

Here's another tricky one in addition to above mapping. Don't know how easy it would be to map it.

## Party Table

Id
Person Id   points to Person

## Identifiers Tables

Id
Party Id
Type Id
Identifier value

## Employee table

Employee Id     No party or person table has foreign key to this table. The employee id is stored in the
identifiers table. so for e.g. The identifier table is used store values for different types. The identifiers for a given party could DriverLicense, EmployeeId, SSN, Credit Card numeber etc, this could be many values.

Sample identifier data

## Id,  PartyId, TypeId, IdentifierValue

1 ,  1,       1,      EMPLID-1234
2 ,  2,       1,      EMPLID-4567
3 ,  3,       1,      EMPLID-34354

I am trying to get my head around this and just can't get it to mapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// this answer assumes you have functional Address, Person, Type, and PersonAddress objects.

public class AddressMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
  public AddressMap()
  {
    Id(x=>x.Id);
    Map(x=>x.Address1);
    Map(x=>x.Address2);
  }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
   public PersonMap()
   {
     Id(x=>x.Id);
     Map(x=>x.First);
     Map(x=>x.Last);
   }
}

public class TypeMap : ClassMap<Type>
{
   public TypeMap()
   {
     Id(x=>x.Id);
     Map(x=>x.TypeName);
   }
}

public class PersonAddressMap : ClassMap<PersonAddress>
{
   public PersonAddressMap()
   {
     Id(x=>x.Id);
     References(x=>x.Person, "PersonId");
     References(x=>x.Address, "AddressId");
     References(x=>x.Type, "TypeId");
   }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't actually join the tables, so your performance still takes a hit because it's making individual queries for each child object.